# Let $AA^*=BB^*$, is this true that, there is an unitary matrix $U$, such that $A=BU$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_n}$ and $AA^*=BB^*$ .

Is this true that, there is an unitary matrix  $U$, such that $A=BU$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).  We have $A = R V$ and $B = R W$ where $R$ is the positive semidefinite square root of $A A^*$ and $V$ and $W$ are unitary.  Then $A = B W^{-1} V$.